# How to validate message body with json schema using apache camel in spring boot application

Tags: json, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am learning apache camel, I have created one spring boot project in which i want to validate the message body with json schema. In my project, I have create route in which i am fetching file from the location in my computer and then passing it to next endpoint where i have applied json validator component and then passed to seda endpoint where i consumed the output.

The code is as follow :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleCamelDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleCamelDemoApplication.class, args);


        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            public void configure() throws Exception {

//
                from("file:C:\\sourceFolder?fileName=test.json&noop=true").convertBodyTo(String.class).to("json-validator:classpath:myschema.json")
                .to("seda:end");
            }

        });
        context.start();
        ConsumerTemplate ct = context.createConsumerTemplate();
        System.out.println(ct.receiveBody("seda:end"));
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.stop();

    }

}
```

the test.json file content is :

```
{
  "id" :1
 }
```

and myschema.json file content is :

```
{
  "id" :1
 }
```

I placed the myschema.json file in src/main/resources folder

I am getting error :

### Message History (complete message history is disabled)

RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [from[file://C:%5CsourceFolder?fileName=test.json&noop=true]                   ] [         2]
    ...
[route1            ] [to1               ] [json-validator:classpath:myschema.json                                        ] [         0]

### Stacktrace

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema.combineCurrentUriWithIds(JsonSchema.java:87) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.29.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema.(JsonSchema.java:75) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.29.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema.(JsonSchema.java:62) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.29.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema.(JsonSchema.java:57) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.29.jar:na]
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.newJsonSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:253) ~[json-schema-validator-1.0.29.jar:na]

Comment: do u have `camel-json-validator-starter` dependency in pom?

Answer (score 0):

Either this is a copy/paste mistake or **your schema file is not a JSON schema**, but the same as your json data.

Take a look at the [Camel docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/json-validator-component.html#_example) for an example of a JSON schema file that can be used with the validator.